# How to stop a tooltip from shifting data in a table once the tooltip is showing

Tags: vue.js, tooltip, css-tables

I have a table. Currently, I want a tooltip to appear on hover, to the right of the hovered on cell. This works currently, but it shifts all of the cells data in the hovered on row to the right. How can I get the tooltip to hover over the next cells data, instead of shifting it?

```
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="row in rows">
            <td v-for="cell in rowKeys" tabIndex="0" v-tooltip.right="{ content: 'Tooltip complete.', class:'tooltip' }" >
                {{row[cell]}}
            </td>        
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves your problem .
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp